# Escape characters in questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, asking-questions

I have ran some strange thing in magento stackexchange. I tried to add a link by `somelink\...\anotherlink` without code quotes and strangely first forward slash went missing like : somelink...\anotherlink. So this means does stack exchange allow escape characters or is this a bug?

Comment: Since the settings for each sub site of the stackexchange network cannot be controlled at site level, I think it's better to post this question on http://meta.stackexchange.com/. That's the general discussion website for the stackexchange network.

Comment: Just to post the answer here for those who are interested: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/258463/172297

Comment: At one time, it was common to recommend taking all vaguely network-related questions to the network-level meta, but that's not a requirement currently. These days, it's just fine to ask about how anything works on the meta of the site you're on; no need to know what's a network-level feature or even be aware of Meta SE if you don't want to!

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments above, this was re-asked and then [answered on the network-wide meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/258463/172297).

The short answer is that `\`, the backslash character, is indeed an escape character in Stack Exchange posts.

To display `somelink\...\anotherlink`, you would have to escape the escape character itself, by entering `somelink\\...\anotherlink` in the editor.